# Community articles rating

Tags: community, lightning-knowledge

I'm trying to understand how to interact with the votes that user can give to an article.

[image]

When a user clicks on this component, where does the vote get stored?

If for example I wanted to query how many thumbs up/thumbs down from an apex method wired to a LWC, would that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's [KnowledgeArticleVoteStat](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticlevotestat.htm)

The erd diagram is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_knowledge.htm) and below:

[image]